# SSL not working properly

Tags: symfony, url, ssl

I am working on Symfony 1.4.

I have install ssl certificate on my server. When I try to access url using

```
http://site_name.com/
```

It works properly and load the site, But when I try it using

```
https://site_name.com/
```

It only shows blank page. There is no error message.

there is also module

```
https://site_name.com/crm
```

and it works fine, But only main site have that problem

Comment: Track it by using https://cryptoreport.thawte.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

Comment: @FieryCat : It's showing "Certificate status:Valid". Is there anything else I need to confirm about ?

Comment: @ParishoshMahale could you share your vhost (without credentials) to find out the possible problem? Check also error/access.log

Comment: Check logs, is the DocumentRoot correct, etc.? You have to treat https://site_name.com like a completely different domain than http://site_name.com, so you need to set the proper values in your admin area

Comment: @kero can you please explain it more or any ref url for that

Comment: I trace request through framework and the request is lost in lib\symfony\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php at    $this->chain[$this->index]->execute($this); this line